# Azure Web Role Startup Action

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-compute-emulator

Okay, the Startup Action option in Azure project in VS2012 is located in the WebRole Properties.

But where is it saved? Is is nowhere in the solution file. After changing the file does not appear modified.

I have to occasionally change these settings after merge, and once changed they are persistent (until the next merge/ modification outside the IDE).

Does someone know where it is saved? I can't find it. no files modified after changing this setting.
[image]

Comment: It's .csdef file in the "cloud project".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no file changes in any of your projects, check if there is a user settings file.  This will be in the same directory as the project file (.csproj, 
.ccproj) but will have am extension with a U in it (I'm not at a machine I can check this on).

Comment: cool. that was it. it becomes even more hard to find, because the user file is saved only on exiting VisualStudio. the file is in the CloudProject and is named '*..ccproj.user' the settings are 'WebRoleSkipLaunchInBrowser' and 'WebRoleHttpsSkipLaunchInBrowser' with the name of the project as node text(e.g:<WebRoleSkipLaunchInBrowser>MyWebProject</WebRoleSkipLaunchInBrowser>)    Thanks!

Comment: TIP: found it, using search by modify datetime: http://superuser.com/questions/488251/how-to-search-for-files-modified-after-a-particular-time

Answer (score 1):

it is in the service definition file (the .CSDEF)

This should be added in the file:

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```

Comment: I am talking about StartupAction in the properties, not a startup-task. Just attached screenshot to make it more clear.

Comment: hmm, good question then.
don't see any file change when that property gets changed

Comment: Yes, that was my point. Seems strange to me. Even more strange is that the setting is reset at random.